# Printing an arraylist heap in a straight line separated by commas at each level

Tags: java, arraylist, heap

So I basically have a max heap stored in an arraylist, for example:

```
[6, 5, 4, 3]
```

I am trying to print the elements of the arraylist to display each level of the heap separated by commas, as well as each element in the same level separated by a " " space. Also, the string must end with a period. for example:

```
6, 5  4, 3.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public void display() {
  String heap = "Current heap is: ";
  for(int i = 0; i <= data.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Math.pow(2, i) && j + Math.pow(2, i) <= data.size(); j++){
      heap = heap +data.get(j + (int)Math.pow(2, i) - 1);
    }
    heap = heap +",";
  }
  System.out.println(heap);
}
```

Output:

```
6,54,3,,,
```

Notice: 'data' is the name of my arraylist.

Comment: If `,,` is being printed then obviously the inner `for` is not being entered into.  This would be because `j` is not `j < Math.pow(2, i) && j + Math.pow(2, i) <= data.size()` - debug and find out.

Comment: the inner for loop is being entered into, otherwise the numbers wouldn't be printing out.

Comment: Only for some values